# Determine whether elements of a pandas sequence contain elements of a different sequence as substrings

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, string-matching

Given the following:

```py
s1 = pd.Series(["onee", "twoo", "threee", "fourr"])
s2 = pd.Series(["one", "two"])
```

How to find `s3` as `[True, True, False, False]`.

This is determined by, for each element in `s1`, if an element from `s2` is a
substring the corresponding element in `s3` should be `True`.

Note - the list sizes can vary, so a solution which depends on there being a
set number of elements in `s2` isn't viable.

I have the following, which I think works, but I don't think is a very nice solution

```py
s1 = pd.Series(["onee", "twoo", "threee", "fourr"])
s2 = pd.Series(["one", "two"])

res = []
for s_2 in s2:
    for s_1 in s1:
        if s_2 in s_1:
            res.append(1)
        else:
            res.append(0)

solution = np.array(res).reshape((2, len(s1))).sum(axis=0)
```

which results in

```
array([1, 1, 0, 0])
```

Comment: @ChrisA how would i handle the case of '|' being within a string of `s2`?

Comment: Use `s1.str.contains('|'.join(s2.str.replace('|', '')))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
s1.str.contains('|'.join(s2.str.replace('|', ''))).astype(int).values
```

Output

```
array([1, 1, 0, 0])
```